# php mail function , checking the value incorrectly

Tags: php

New to php, the mail sends but send empty mail. it does not check for values

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "info@tere.com"; // this is your Email address
    $email = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $message = $name . " " . $email . " ". $company;


    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$message,$headers);

    mail($from,$headers2,$headers2,$message); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

I guess i am not checking values.alot the value when i add them in the form, they appear in the subject of the mail.

Comment: Dump or print the `$message` variable, what does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend to validate the form at frontend, but anyways you can always check for if the values are empty or not by using:

```php
if("" != trim($_POST['email']) && "" != trim($_POST['name']) && "" != trim($_POST['company'])){
        //Here all the values are present and not empty

        $company    =  $_POST['company'];
        $name    =  $_POST['name'];
        $user_email      =  $_POST['email'];


        $to = "info@tere.com"; // this is your Email address
        $message = $name . " " . $user_email . " ". $company;


        $subject = 'SUBJECT OF EMAIL';
        $headers = 'From: info@tere.com' . "\r\n" .
                   'Reply-To: info@tere.com' . "\r\n" .
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


         mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);// send email to yourself

         mail($user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);// send email to client
         echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $user_email . ", we will contact you shortly.";

    }else{
       //Here one of the values is empty 
       echo "Email not sent!";
    }
```

**Update**

Copy the following lines and put them at the top of your code and see if you get any error!

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: i have tried, the code does work( mine above).Is there an alternative to use apart from isset? it works when i say !isset

Comment: Is there an alternative to use apart from isset? it works when i say !isset( mail sends)

Comment: i get this. 32759
Notice: Undefined variable: from in /home/carfwoo/public_html/contact/index.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: headers2 in /home/carfwoo/public_html/contact/index.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: from in /home/carfwoo/public_html/contact/index.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined variable: first_name in /home/carfwoo/public_html/contact/index.php on line 25
Mail Sent. Thank you , we will contact you shortly.

Comment: but i get the email. Do you perhaps have an alternative script? i been struggling with this since Saturday morning. I just need to get name,company,email .

Comment: just checked, didnt receive mail,

Comment: Above code is working as i test it before posting and I have received the email. kindly check your spam!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$message= wordwrap($message,70);
```

This is because it is requirement to wrap the message at 70 characters.